# How would I define every member in the same guild as bot, then send message

Tags: bots, discord, discord.js

Basically I want to send a message to every member within the same guild as a bot.

This code is working only for people within one guild.

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  message.guild.members.cache.forEach(member => {
  if (member.id != client.user.id && !member.user.bot) member.send(embed);
 });
}, 5000);
```

But It should be like, if the bot is in the same guild as a member it should send him a message.
ex. If bot is in 10 guilds it should send a message to people within 10 guilds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get every guild the bot is in, then every member of all of those guilds.

```js
client.guilds.cache.forEach(guild => {
    guild.members.cache.forEach(member => {
        if (member.id !== client.user.id && !member.user.bot) member.send(embed);
    });
});
```

This seems mildly spammy and against TOS but I'm here to answer questions, not judge someone's intentions.

Comment: I won't use it I was just wondering if it's possible, I fetch guilds channels named "auto-partnership" then send a message there